# Detecting an invalid char

Tags: c#, char, binaryreader, argumentexception

When reading chars from binary file with `BinaryReader`, I often come across malformed data that cannot be read as a char. I get an `ArgumentException` thrown.

Is there any way for me to anticipate when the next character will throw an exception so instead of trying to read it (which will throw an exception) to be able to deal with it without the costly operation?

`BinaryReader.ReadChar();`

Which inputs will cause `ArgumentException` to be thrown?

Comment: The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.readchar(v=vs.110).aspx) suggests using `ReadChars` instead.

Comment: I know, but it was throwing the same exceptions when reading a single char...

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, just figured it out:

```
char next = (char)reader.ReadByte();

if (Char.IsSurrogate(next)) {
    return "Non-valid char value";
}
```

Feel free to post a better solution.